# Winforms: Form lags when trying to move/Drag it on windows 10

Tags: c#, winforms, move, drag, lag

Not sure if the title makes sense.
I have a form that has several panels that each has a form associated with them.
I call this form the "mainForm", and when I move/drag it across my screen it lags a lot, the mouse also feels extremely unresponsive.

When you first open it and it doesn't lag at all, however after having some controls on screen it lag becomes noticeable and when I have over 100 controls it becomes very laggy. IF I don't move it, the program runs fine and everything in itself is good, it's only when I try to move it.

I'm not entirely sure how this works, but when you move it, does it recalculate something on the form and the controls and are on it? If so is it possible to disable that when trying to move and reenabling it when we stopped moving?

Changing to WPF at this point is not possible due to time constraints.

Hopefully, someone has had an issue like this before.
Any tips are extremely appreciated.

Thank you for your time guys!

Comment: I am a little confused about the forms in panels on a "mainForm". 
I think there might be a slight issue where you are causing an awful lot of "redraw" events to happen. 
There is no need to embed forms in an existing form. If you wish to have controls added to a panel, you can do so. Could be that when you drag n drop, the redraw event is triggering all forms to redraw (shown or not)
I would not associate forms with panels on a "parent form" anyway? This seems .. an odd choice?

Please include enough code to reproduce your issue

Comment: Learn how to build UserControls instead of using Forms as child Containers. UserControls provide a Designer, exactly as a Form.

Comment: @MortenBork Thank you for the reply.
I have buttons that when pressed adds and opens a form on a specific panel that is on the "main" form. I have tried user controls, but, it was causing undesired results, as such I switched to forms. 
So in this case I would not be able to simply add the controls to the panel, and adding them by code would be a big hassle. 
Moving the Form around causes redraw events? Does this also happen if a user control is inside the form? Because It lags the most when I add a form to a panel that has a user control inside with a lot of controls.

Comment: @Jimi If only I thought of that earlier :(

Comment: @UltraWazer 

try to make a branch of your code, where you do not have the forms linked to panels. 
Try using 
private readonly TableLayoutPanel tlp = new TableLayoutPanel();

For adding your buttons or other UI components to your form instead. 
You should be able to copy paste "most" of your code into the layoutpanel, and add them as controls. That allow for a new form to "pop-up" if you need a "new form" to display, otherwise, you can simply remove and add new layoutpanels to your user controls, to receive the same function? I believe.

Comment: Again, please add some code so that we can reproduce the error.. 
Otherwise we are guessing, sometimes wildly, what the issue "might be"

Comment: *I have tried user controls, but, it was causing undesired results*: I don't see how that can happen and you are not explain this either. -- If the Window *lags* while it's dragged, then you have events that constantly repaint the Windows' content (the outer Form container, the dumbed-down Form containers, child of Panels, the Controls inside these Forms which, possibly, generate cascading events that cause the same problem). You didn't mention whether you're using 3rd party Controls of what these Controls as doing, thus there's no way to determine what's causing the problem (or starts it).

Comment: @Jimi Yes, I didn't realize it could that every control side of it is trigging events while the form is being moved. However, it makes sense, I will validate it. I reckon the main culprit is a form that has a parent user control which can have other user controls ranging from a few to several dozens to hundreds, all added via code at runtime. This logic is repeated to other forms, but since the main user control in those don't have a lot of child user controls in them, they don't lag when moved.

Comment: @Jimi Do you know if there is a way to suppress/stop any redraw/repaint event from triggering when moving a window? Or some way to mitigate it?

Comment: @MortenBork I could share some code, however, I don't know what to share, since some forms can have over 3k lines of code. I explained to above to another user in a bit more detail what the culprit for the lag is.

Comment: @MortenBork I ended up solving it. The issue was happening even with your code. It was simply too many controls and it was going crazy when moved. 
So in my "mainForm" when it moves I clear the main panel I have in "ResizeBegin" and add the sub panels back to the main panel in "ResizeEnd" and it works flawlessly so far. Since I also saved the current panel being displayed i can make that one display first.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351004/dragmove-not-working-when-quickly-dragging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving it. The issue was happening even with the code that Morten Bork shared. It was simply too many controls (I had about 500 controls in the test I did) and the form was going crazy slow when moved.

The user Jimi input on the matter was key, after looking around in the events I tried the following and it solved my issue. So hopefully someone that needs a solution for something similar can use my solution.

In my "mainForm" when it moves I clear the main panel I have in "ResizeBegin" and add the sub panels back to the main panel in "ResizeEnd" and it works flawlessly so far. Since I also saved the current sub panel being displayed I can make that one display first.

Comment: Windows used to cope with this fine, but at some point Microsoft released an update to Windows 10 which makes moving windows perform abysmally with more than a small number of child windows. It causes problems for a lot of different software, including some major ones. MS know about it but have done nothing for years, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and I found a workaround but it doesn't make sense.

I overrode the WndProc to see what messages were being sent during the form movement that might be slowing it down. 5 messages cycle through while moving the form:

- 3: WM_MOVE
- 534: WM_MOVING
- 70: WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING
- 36: WM_GETMINMAXINFO
- 71: WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED

At first, the only Windows message that I suspected could require heavy processing with a lot of controls is WM_GETMINMAXINFO, because it might be evaluating the size of controls, and would take longer for more controls.

Surprisingly, the override and addition of a Debug.WriteLine statement was enough to remove the lag altogether.

```
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"msg: {message.Msg}, wparam:{message.WParam}, lparam:{message.LParam}, lparam:{message.HWnd}");
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

The presence of the Debug.WriteLine statement seems to change the behavior of the method such that the form moves smoothly with no lag. If I compile in release mode or comment out the Debug statement, then the form lags again. It doesn't make much sense.

**UPDATE/SOLUTION**: New info. This lag occurs only when dragging the form with my Rival 650 Wireless mouse. It does not lag when I drag the window with the mouse pad built into the laptop. Perhaps the mouse driver is doing something goofy or it's producing mouse move events too rapidly, and somehow the addition of a debug statement slows things down enough to disrupt the lag.

If I lower the polling rate of the mouse from 1000hz to 500hz there is still lag, but if I lower it to 250hz then the window dragging lag disappears altogether. So this seems to be caused by the high polling/event rate of the mouse and the way Windows handles the events.

Comment: Hello @triynko, Thank you for your answer, and apologies for the late reply. At the time0 my way of making it better it was to simply, making all of the main panels of the forms invisible, once you moved, and make them visible again only after you stopped moving. Your away is still the much better option, I would say :)

Answer (score 0):

I once created this in winforms:

```
public class FormExt : Form
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///     Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private IContainer components;

       
        private readonly TableLayoutPanel tlp = new TableLayoutPanel();

        public FormExt(IFormExtension formExtension)
        {
            FormExtension = formExtension;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public FormExt()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public Panel LowerLeft { get; set; }
        public BorderedPanel LowerRight { get; set; }
        public Panel UpperLeft { get; set; }

        public IFormExtension FormExtension { get; set; }

        public virtual void FormExtended_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (FormExtension.Parent != null)
            {
                FormExtension.Parent.Refresh();
                FormExtension.Parent.Show();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && components != null) components.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        ///     Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        ///     the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            //TableLayoutPanel
            tlp.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            tlp.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            tlp.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 100F));
            tlp.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.AutoSize, 500F));
            tlp.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 50F));
            tlp.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize, 550F));
            tlp.CellBorderStyle = TableLayoutPanelCellBorderStyle.None;

            tlp.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
            tlp.Margin = new Padding(0);
            tlp.Padding = new Padding(0);

            //Upper background color
            Color myRgbColor = new Color();
#if DEBUG
            myRgbColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0);
#else
            myRgbColor = Color.FromArgb(10, 19, 39);
#endif
            //LowerLeft
            LowerLeft = new Panel();
            LowerLeft.BackColor = Color.White;
            LowerLeft.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

            //UpperLeft
            UpperLeft = new Panel();
            UpperLeft.BackColor = myRgbColor;

            UpperLeft.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.None;
            UpperLeft.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

            //LowerRight
            LowerRight = new BorderedPanel();
            LowerRight.Size = new Size(600, 550);
            LowerRight.BackColor = Color.White;
            LowerRight.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

            components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.Font;
            ClientSize = new Size(800, 450);
            FormClosing += FormExtended_Closing;
            Text = "";

            this.Controls.Add(tlp);
            tlp.SetColumnSpan(UpperLeft, 2);
            LowerLeft.Margin = new Padding(0);
            LowerLeft.Padding = new Padding(0);
            tlp.Controls.Add(LowerLeft, 0, 1);
            UpperLeft.Margin = new Padding(0);
            UpperLeft.Padding = new Padding(0);
            tlp.Controls.Add(UpperLeft, 0, 0);
            LowerRight.Margin = new Padding(0);
            LowerRight.Padding = new Padding(0);
            tlp.Controls.Add(LowerRight, 1, 1);
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

To be a template for a layout.
And then I would add buttons on the left lower, content in lowerright, and upper left and right for a logo and some possible page mechanics like filter lists etc.

The nice concept is you have on 1 active form at a time. And while the otherforms by still exist in memory, they remain inactive, don't receive events unless you deliberately pass them. As far as I know. I at least, have never had the issue you describe using this component. But I never loaded "hundreds of controls" at the same time, on the same form. That is just ... to much responsibility for a single form to have.

The formExtension interface:

```
public interface IFormExtension
    {
        public Form Parent { get; set; }
    }
```

This is just one way of creating multiple forms, that each have their own "table-layout" you can either overload this particular layout -> (Or the one you have made)

Or you can simple redefine a new layout placed in a TableLayoutPanel, and then your form should work as intended.

Comment: I will give this a go, and see if I can apply anything I have that lags to this. 
I think the main culprit might be that I have a lot of user controls that might be triggering a lot of repaint/redraw events like another user here pointed out.
Thank you :)